# pass control the value of input

Tags: asp.net

Perhaps the topic name was chosen incorrectly, I will try to formulate my question. Is it possible to pass to the control an input value that has id = "dateToWork". Tried something like this

```html
<CTR:datePickerKolibri3 ID="KolibriDatePicker1" runat="server" InToField="dateArrival" DayAfter=<% $(#dateToWork).val()%>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to do what you want i think, me i create a usercontrol with the control and i add properties.

In your case i do that :

Create a new usercontrol
Add  inside
In UserControl.ascx.designer set datePickerKolibri3 to public

Add in code behind of the USerControl  :

```
  Private p_datetowork As String

   Public Property Datetowork As String
        Get
            Return p_datetowork
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            p_datetowork = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

And put your UserControl in the page you want and you can pass and access to the properties Datetowork

```
 <CTR:UserControl ID="myUserControl" runat="server" Datetowork="my_date" >
```

or in Code behind :

```
myUserControl.Datetowork = "my_date"
```

If i underdstand your problem :D